# Вывести зависимости пакета рекурсивно

Tags: golang, зависимости

Как в *Go* вывести зависимости пакета рекурсивно?  То есть,
зависимости зависимостей, и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью команды `go list`.  Пример:

```sh
$ go list -f '{{range .Deps}}{{printf "%s\n" .}}{{end}}' bytes
errors
internal/bytealg
internal/cpu
internal/race
internal/reflectlite
io
runtime
runtime/internal/atomic
runtime/internal/math
runtime/internal/sys
sync
sync/atomic
unicode
unicode/utf8
unsafe
$
```

Документация:
https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules.